# cordova app configuration for android

Tags: android, cordova

I have tabs and pages in my app I have build it locally and the build was successful then I connected my phone and run it on my phone. App opens up and nothing is clickable. Only static items are visible. It seems like sql storage isn't enable because items are dynamically generated in the app.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your Cordova configuration you should consider the plugins for types of functionality do you want in your app after cordova. Try this one hopefully it will useful for you.
https://codesundar.com/lesson/cordova-sqlite-storage/

Comment: I am not using any extra plugin except cordova-plugin-whitelist

Comment: I think I need to do some configurations in config.xml file to make it work. It's not just item display but nothing is clickable as well.

Comment: yes you need to configure your config.xml,  refer that link in that link they have mentioned about the plugin that you need to configure, it is just a command that you need to apply and then just build your app using cordova.